# how long does the care take to reach the last pole algebra word problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There are 20 poles with a constant distance between each pole. A car takes 22 seconds to reach the 12th pole starting from the first pole, with a constant speed between each pole. how many seconds will it take to reach the last pole?

Is the answer 36 seconds?

since $\frac{22} {12}  = 1.83 $

$1.83 \times 20 = 36.67 $

Comment: Consider the function f(n) = distance from the first pole to the nth pole. Write down what you think the formula is. What does your formula give for f(1)? Does that make sense?

Comment: if you have two poles, there is only one distance between them

Comment: than i am not sure how to work this out?

Comment: am so far off, i dont think its as 'complicated' as you guys are saying

Comment: Theres a trick.  If you start at the *first* pole and not some "zero" starting place then the car only travels the distance of *eleven* (not twelve) distances and needs to travel *nineteen* (not twenty) distances.  So the answer is $\frac {21}{11}\times 19$ and not $\frac {22}{12}\times 20$.  It's just that one trick (which is kind of mean...)

Comment: Had the car started at the 7th pole how would you have solved this.  If it started at the 6th how would you have solved this?  If it started at the 2nd how would you have solved this?  If the car had started one pole distance *before* the first, how would you have solved this?

Comment: $1 + 19 = 20$ and $1 + 20 = 21\ne 20$.  And $1 + 11 = 12$ and $1 + 12 = 13 \ne 12$.  Starting at $1$ instead of starting at $0$ makes a *!!!big!!!* difference.

Comment: @fleablood: That should be $\frac{22}{11}\times 19$, not $\frac{21}{11}\times 19$.

Comment: Yeah you are right.  Somehow I misread it as being 22 posts and a clock measuring as going from 1 second to 22 seconds.  Mild dyslexia, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Count the green distances between the poles.  Notice: There are !!!$19$!!! of them.  Not $20$.  This is because you are starting at point $1$.  The car never traveled between $0$ to $1$.

It *started* at $1$.  And notice to get to post number $12$ (in red), the car only drove !!$11$!!! of the green distances.

So it took $22$ seconds to go $11$ distances.  That is it took $\frac {22}{11} = 2$ seconds to go $1$ distance.

It will take $19*2 = 38$ seconds to go $19$ distances and to end up at post number $20$.

....

Also notice.  If we relabeled the posts so that the first post is label $0$ and the second post is labelled $1$ and so on... well, how does that change the math.  Nothing has changed but the label.  Which labelling system makes more sense if you are *starting* at the first post and measuring the distances you travel?
[image]

Comment: wow, thank you for the very in depth picture and explanation

Answer (score 2):

No, you have a [fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error).  You should count the spaces between the poles.  There are $11$ spaces between the first $12$ poles.

Comment: so there's another 8 spaces until the 20th pole? how does this solve the problem ?

Comment: You were given that it takes $22$ seconds to cover the first $11$ spaces, so it is $2$ seconds per space, so $38$ for all $19$ spaces.

Comment: but, if it takes 22 seconds to cover 12 equally paced poles, than dividing 22 by 12 gives you the time taken for each pole, so why is this concept wrong?

Comment: @italy  You start moving at the first pole, so $12 - 1 = 11$ new poles are reached in the first $22$ seconds.

Comment: Because the time is spent in the distance between the poles, not at each pole.  Each pole is just a point on the ground.  Say the poles are at $100$ m intervals.  They are at points $0,100,200,\ldots 2100$ meters.  To pass $12$ poles the car drives $1100$ meters.

Comment: "so why is this concept wrong?"  Because the car *never* drove to the first pole.  It *started* at the first pole.  And the 20th pole is not 19 distances away from 1 which is the starting point.  .... Here's a thought experiment.  What if the poles were numbered $0$ to $19$ instead of $1$ to $20$.  Other than the *labels* everything is exactly the same.  Is the answer any different?  And what *is* the answer.

Comment: thank you, i understand fully now!